# Remove nginx from port 80 & add apache instead

Tags: linux, apache, nginx

i am using xfilesharing script on my website & have installed VestaCP on server.Website giving error when i am trying to upload files more than 200 MB.i have talked to support & they asked me to use Apache instead Nginx.i stopped nginx on my domain & the error still persists.agaun called support & they said nginx still on port 80 (Even after restarting server).support told me to set apache port to 80 instead.
i don't know how to set it.i am new to linux & never used up VestaCP.can anyone help me with a step by step guide on how can i set apache to listen port 80 & nginx to not to listen port 80.
please give a step by step guide if you have.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

keep nginx in place

/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 300M 
post_max_size = 300M
```

nginx
add

```
http {
    #...
         client_max_body_size 300m;     
#... }
```

> service php5-fpm restart; service nginx restart

Comment: Can you gimme a step by step guide on how to do it ?